# Is it possible to control the mouse tracking speed (how much the cursor moves in response to motion of the mouse) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I am new to Javascript.

I want to run an online (in-browser) experiment that requires users to move a cursor through moving targets. I have code to collect mouse position:

```
document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
    setInterval(catchDots, 1); // setInterval repeats every X ms -> 1000 Hz
​
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
        var eventDoc, doc, body;
​
        event = event || window.event; // IE-ism
        mousePos = {
            x: event.pageX,
            y: event.pageY
        };
    }
```

However, I would like to be able to control the mouse/trackpad tracking speed, (i.e., the amount the cursor moves in response to motion of the mouse/finger on a trackpad). I would have thought that this would require either 1) being able to control the tracking speed or 2) knowing the tracking speed to be able to counter as appropriate. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, only if you 1: Hide the default cursor `cursor: none` 2. (obviously) create your own custom cursor that will move in respect to the real (hidden) pointer. - So No, you cannot change the cursor behavior of the native OS pointer - if that was the question.

Comment: Thanks Roko. I want to control the cursor in the experiment relative to the motion of the user's mouse/trackpad input, not relative to the user's cursor (which is your solution as I understand?). I want the tracking speed (motion of the cursor displayed in the experiment relative to the motion of the user's mouse/trackpad input) to be constant for all users. I would have thought the only way I can achieve this is by first knowing the tracking speed used on each user's computer?